# Tesseract not able to recognize characters even for a high quality Image

Tags: image-processing, tesseract, leptonica

I am doing the process of cleaning up and image using leptonica and then passing it to tesseract for OCR.However it is not able to recognize the characters even though the image is of high quality.The image specifications are as follows.

```
1 bpp, uncompressed, 1280 * 960 , 300dpi horizontal and vertical resolution
```

Following are the image processing operations I carry out in sequence using leptonica

```
pixConvertTo8
pixBackgroundNormSimple
pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold
pixContrastTRC {Regarding this - I am passing high values like 1.0 or even 5.0 but image doesnt really change}
pixFindSkew
pixRotate { rotate by angle found by pixFindSkew}
pixRotate90 {do this 4 times to read image in all 4 orientations}
pixClipRectangle {crop image}
Finally tesseract command
```

I get garbage characters in the output.A sample Input Image is as follows.
[image]

The output that i get is as follows

```
Final K-1
II]
s h d | K-1 ,.,
(FÂ°o.~?nâ€˜i&1) 5/>.Â©12 mm E2â€˜;
Deparlrnenl of tho Treasury , ,
I 1 I l I
â€˜mama, Ravenuo SGMW For cnlundm your 201), â€˜ " Â°FÂ°$ "'100fTIO
or lax yum boqmnnnq 7 _ 20\Q_
â€˜ 7660
and ondmg _  W vv I go
Beneï¬ciary's Share of Income, Deductions,
cl'editS, etc. F 800 buck 01 loam nnd lnstruoï¬‚onsÂ»
___lnformatI0n About mo Estate or Trust
â€˜ Ordmary d|v|dm
i 12113
 _
â€˜; Quahfmd dlVIdG
\ 8132
3 1
Net shun-term
A Estate's at trust's omgiuym ldonnlmnluon numbol
56-0987654
B Estate's u trustâ€˜: namo
ESTATE OF MARTHA SMITH
0 FiducÂ§ary's name, address, clly, smluâ€˜ and /IP codo
N01 long~lerm c
\ 24043 
u 
â€˜ 28% vale gann
Ti
Unreptumd 5
Omar porï¬‚oho 4
nonbuslness lï¬‚l
/\..4........ L. ._.._ ,.
```

What Should i do to improve the accuracy.

Part 2:

I tried to follow [this link](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html#_config_files_and_augmenting_with_user_data).And created a eng.user-words.traineddata file and bazaar.train file and tried to run with "bazaar" as additional parameter.but i get "read_params_file: can't open bazaar error".
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @nnm, Did you get any further help regarding processing of these tax documents using tesseract? We have a requirement to implement the same in one of our projects.

Answer (score 1):

For part one,

I don't know if the image you posted up here is the actual one you've been trying to scan but when I tried it, I got this:-

---

> Department oi the Treasury Internal Revenue Service
>
> For cnlundm your V019, 1 ‘ '"l0T°5' |nC0m0
>
> or tax yam boqlnnlnq , 2o12_ ‘ 7660 and ondlng I go 2: ‘ Ordinary
>   dlvndm " “T ' x 12113
>
> 1; Quali?ed dwnda ‘ 8132 Netshun-term:
>
> M Not long ~terrn c
>
> i 24043 Ab ‘ 2896 ralagann
>
> Bene?ciary’s Share of Income, Deductions, Cfedits, etc. 5 800 back oi
>   form nnd Instruc?ons
>
> | Partl Information About the state or Trust
>
> A Estate's or IvLsl's omuoym Idonnlncnluon numhu
>
> 56-0987654
>
> 8 Estate‘: a trust‘: namo
>
> ESTATE OF MARTHA SMITH
>
> M: Unreptumd 5
>
> 017161 portioho : nonbuslness Inl
>
> C Fiduc§ary's name, address, city, smlul an-(V1/If’ Eooo

---

It's not great but it seems a bit better than what you got. I'm using Tesseract v3 on Windows.
My basic command was:

```
-    tesseract.exe  nnm.tif  nnm
```

For part two,

your `bazaar` file should be in the `configs` folder

```
 .....\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\configs\bazaar
```

and there's some requirements for it to be saved in a particular format, like `UTF8` with only a `LF` at the end of the line not a `CR + LF`, it seems to be quite fussy about the file formats.

you can get a copy of it from http://code.metager.de/source/raw/google/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/configs/bazaar

I made a digits config file that I used for scanning some images where I was only interested in the numbers and that worked fine:

```
-   tesseract.exe  scanfile.jpg  scanfile  digits
```

The documentation for `Tesseract` is pretty poor and it doesn't work well on a PC.

Answer (score 0):

For part one,

I think you should consider the preprocessing done by Capture2Text. It is using both Leptonica and Tesseract to OCR the images.

I am not sure about part 2.